# Obter Tamanho do Arquivo em Bytes no Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, file-upload, internet-explorer-8

Estou validando o tamanho do arquivo anexado na minha página antes do upload usando o seguinte codigo:

```
var tamanhoArquivo = parseInt(document.getElementById("documento").files[0].size);
        if(tamanhoArquivo > 2097152){ //MAX_FILE_SIZE = 2097152 Bytes
            alert("TAMANHO DO ARQUIVO EXCEDE O PERMITIDO (2MB)!");
            return false;
        }
```

Esta validação esta funcionando perfeitamente em todos os navegadores, menos na versão 8 do IE, onde ele diz que "Não é possível obter a propriedade '0' de referência indefinida ou nula".

Alguma sugestão para a validação do tamanho também no IE 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Internet Explorer 8 não suporta Múltiplos Arquivos. Apenas o IE 10 em diante aceita. [Documentação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Por isso esta dando erro ao tentar acessar a posição `0`.

Não tem como pegar, utilizando apenas javascript, o tamanho do Arquivo no IE 8 nem no IE 9.

Veja os Navegadores que podem utilizar o [File Api](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).

Comment: Existe alguma outra forma de validar ainda no front-end no IE 8 e 9 ?

Comment: Dei uma procurada aqui para te responder esta questão, e não encontrei. O que vi foram pessoas utilizando applets em java para fazer esse tratamento, entretanto não estava muito claro então deixei de lado.