# validar imagem input file multiple jquery de 4 formas

Tags: jquery, input, multiple

Boa noite pessoal, tenho um input file multiple e preciso fazer 4 validações antes de enviar o form.

1) Limitar o numero de imagens enviadas em 10

2) imagens tem que ser do tipo jpeg ou png ( colocar apenas um accept no html ja resolve isso por completo?)

3) cada imagem n pode ser superior a 2mb

4) largura minima da imagem deve ser de 600px

Podem me dar uma força? eu estava fazendo toda essa validação depois de enviar o arquivo para o servidor, mas fica ruim enviar tudo para depois testar.

Comment: Poste o código que você já tem até o momento.

Comment: de jquery eu não tenho nada, pesquisei mas não achei nada que me servia pois todos que vi eram para input de um arquivo único e eu preciso para multiple

Answer (score 0):

Olá

1) Pode encontrar sua solução [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105411/how-to-limit-maximum-items-on-a-multiple-input-input-type-file-multiple)

2) Pode procurar mais no google pesquisando como validar extensões de arquivos. Aqui temos mais uma [solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4234589/validation-of-file-extension-before-uploading-file)

3) Solução [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41938/obter-tamanho-do-arquivo-em-bytes-no-java-script)

4) Em JavaScript:

```js
var largura = document.getElementById("imagem").width; // retorna a largura
    var altura = document.getElementById("imagem").height; // retorna a altura
```

Em Jquery

```js
var largura = $('#imagem').width(); // retorna a largura
var altura = $('#imagem').height(); // retorna a altura
```

Agora é contigo, basta criar as function necessárias antes de enviar para o servidor.

Comment: sobre a questão 4 => se o input file é multiple não vai dar problema na hora de pegar esse width e height não?

Comment: De qualquer forma tu vai precisar verificar cada arquivo, então teria que capturar a lista de arquivos do input multiple e verifcar cada um.